# CSS Div Arrangement Float Issue

Tags: html, css

I am a bit new to css and I am having trouble with getting my navigation and divs to align. I am trying to get the navigation bar to extend 60% of the way. The left div to be under the nav bar. An the right div to be 40% on the right. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 12pt
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 3px;
  clear: both;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #990000;
  clear: both;
}

.right h2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

/* navigation */

.nav ul {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  opacity: 0.98;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.navcontainer {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Welcome to Scribbled</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- This is the nav bar-->

  <div class="navcontainer">
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
      <li><a href="#homepage">Homepage</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#first">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#second">Photos</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Left Panel -->

  <div class="left">

    <div id="homepage">
      <h1>Homepage</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="first">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <h2>Posted by Someone on June 10, 2011 * Comments(64)* Full Article </h2>
      <p>This is
        <bold>Scribbled</bold>, Lorem Ipsum is simply <span style="color: red">dummy </span> text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
        type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
        Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>


    <div id="second">
      <h1>Photos</h1>
      <img src="images/flower.jpg" class="flower" alt="Flower">
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Right Panel -->
  <div class="right">

    <div class="search">
      <h2>
   Search
  </h2>

      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter keywords here..." required>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="Aliquam tempus">
      <h2>Aliquam tempus</h2>
      <p>
        Mauris of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum ha
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Categories">
      <h2>Categories</h2>
      <p>
        Alquam libero
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `clear: both;` from `.right` and add `box-sizing:border-box;` to both `.left` and `.right` (as [@nevermind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2045185/nevermind) pointed out). Also, you may or not need to add `display: inline-block` to both.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 12pt
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 3px;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #990000;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.right h2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
/* navigation */

.nav ul {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  opacity: 0.98;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}
;
 .nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
.navcontainer {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Welcome to Scribbled</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- This is the nav bar-->

  <div class="navcontainer">
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
      <li><a href="#homepage">Homepage</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#first">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#second">Photos</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Left Panel -->

  <div class="left">

    <div id="homepage">
      <h1>Homepage</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="first">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <h2>Posted by Someone on June 10, 2011 * Comments(64)* Full Article </h2>
      <p>This is
        <bold>Scribbled</bold>, Lorem Ipsum is simply <span style="color: red">dummy </span> text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
        type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
        Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>


    <div id="second">
      <h1>Photos</h1>
      <img src="images/flower.jpg" class="flower" alt="Flower">
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Right Panel -->
  <div class="right">

    <div class="search">
      <h2>
   Search
  </h2>

      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter keywords here..." required>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="Aliquam tempus">
      <h2>Aliquam tempus</h2>
      <p>
        Mauris of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum ha
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Categories">
      <h2>Categories</h2>
      <p>
        Alquam libero
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: It would be really worth mentioning that the problem was `clear:both` on `.right`.

Comment: Actually, OP can keep 60% on the left div: http://jsfiddle.net/t58m8e2z/ box-sizing:border-box will take care about it...

Comment: @imtheman okay thanks. I think that fixed some of the issues. How do I extend the right div to take up the entire height? And also extend the navigation bar to the right until it hits the right div? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @DavidL Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand about your question maybe this is what are you looking for

```css
body {

      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }

    h2 {

      font-size: 12pt

    }

    .left {

      float: left;

      width: 60%;

      background-color: #cccccc;

      clear: both;

    }

    .right {

      float: right;

      height: 100%;

      width: 40%;

      background-color: #990000;

    }

    .left h1, .left h2, .left p {
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      }

    .right h2 {

      background-color: black;

      color: white;

    }

    /* navigation */

    .nav ul {

      display: inline;

      background-color: #444;

      text-align: center;

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

    }

    .nav li {

      float: left;

      list-style: none;

      background-color: #5f5f5f;

      opacity: 0.98;

      line-height: 40px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .nav li:hover {
      background-color: #000;
      }

    .nav a {

      text-decoration: none;

      color: #fff;

      display: block;

    }

    ;

    .nav a.active {

      background-color: #fff;

      color: #444;

    }

    .navcontainer {

      width: 60%;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #5f5f5f;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <title>Welcome to Scribbled</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      
      <!-- This is the nav bar-->

      <div class="navcontainer">
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
          <li><a href="#homepage">Homepage</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#first">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#second">Photos</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Left Panel -->

      <div class="left">

        <div id="homepage">
          <h1>Homepage</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="first">
          <h1>About</h1>
          <h2>Posted by Someone on June 10, 2011 * Comments(64)* Full Article </h2>
          <p>This is
            <bold>Scribbled</bold>, Lorem Ipsum is simply <span style="color: red">dummy </span> text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
            type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
            Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>


        <div id="second">
          <h1>Photos</h1>
          <img src="images/flower.jpg" class="flower" alt="Flower">
        </div>

      </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Right Panel -->
      <div class="right">

        <div class="search">
          <h2>
       Search
      </h2>

          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter keywords here..." required>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="Aliquam tempus">
          <h2>Aliquam tempus</h2>
          <p>
            Mauris of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum ha
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="Categories">
          <h2>Categories</h2>
          <p>
            Alquam libero
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
```

You should always take seriously padding's, margin's and borders when you set the width or height with '**%**'

Comment: How do I get the right div to extend to the full height? I think that would solve everything? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, i would use different approach. **display:table**, could be the solution.

HTML:

```
 <!-- This is the nav bar-->

  <div class="navcontainer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#homepage">Homepage</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#first">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#second">Photos</a>
      </li>
 </ul>
  </div>

<div id="content">
  <!-- Left Panel -->

  <div class="left">

    <div id="homepage">
      <h1>Homepage</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="first">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <h2>Posted by Someone on June 10, 2011 * Comments(64)* Full Article </h2>
      <p>This is
        <bold>Scribbled</bold>, Lorem Ipsum is simply <span style="color: red">dummy </span> text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
        type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
        Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>


    <div id="second">
      <h1>Photos</h1>
      <img src="images/flower.jpg" class="flower" alt="Flower">
    </div>

  </div>



  <!-- Right Panel -->
  <div class="right">

    <div class="search">
      <h2>
            Search
        </h2>

      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter keywords here..." required>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="Aliquam tempus">
      <h2>Aliquam tempus</h2>
      <p>
        Mauris of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum ha
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Categories">
      <h2>Categories</h2>
      <p>
        Alquam libero
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 12pt
}

#content {
    display:table;
}

.left {

  width: 60%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 3px;
display:table-cell;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.right {
 display:table-cell;
box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #990000;
  padding:5px;

}

.right h2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

/* navigation */

.navcontainer {
  width: 60%;
  display:table;
}


.navcontainer ul {
  display:table-row;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navcontainer li {
display:table-cell;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  opacity: 0.98;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.navcontainer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.navcontainer {
  width: 60%;
  display:table;
}
```

So, div with id `#content` is added as a container for left and right block... `ul` element is created, and one redundant div removed (also, one wrong closing div tag removed too). Now you have extended navigation and two blocks, without using of floats.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwh1tr46/